# Symfony2: assetic declared twice in deps

Tags: symfony, assetic

I just upgraded Symfony to the 2.0.12 version. And after a quick look to the deps file, I realized that Assetic was declared twice, and in two different versions.

```
[AsseticBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
    version=v1.0.1
```

and

```
[assetic]
    git=http://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic.git
    version=v1.0.3
```

Why is that ? Is there a specific reason or is it an oversight ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assetic` and `AsseticBundle` are two different things.

`assetic` is the underlying library used by `AsseticBundle`. It is a standalone library and does not depend on `Symfony` directly. It can be used by any PHP projects out there.

On the other part, the bundle provides a tight integration of the library with `Symfony` so you don't have to code a lot to use it. Because it is a bundle, the `AsseticBundle` depends on `FrameworkBundle` so it must be used with `Symfony`.

So, `assetic` doesn't depend on anything. `AsseticBundle` depends on `assetic` but also on `FrameworkBundle` which is the core of the `Symfony` framework.

You can see that these are two different things by the git repo urls used:

`assetic` => http://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic.git 
`AsseticBundle` => http://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle.git

Which are two different repos, so two different things but tightly coupled together. In a sense both could have been packaged together, but having two distinct entity enable uses outside of `Symfony`.

P.S. Beaten by @elnur by a few seconds :)

Regards, 
Matt

Answer (score 2):

One of them is a lib which you can use in plain PHP and the other one is a bundle to integrate it with Symfony2.